# Process.Start() 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to subscribe to process.OutputDataReceived. Seeing no result (the event is not firing on output) I followed an example on [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.100).aspx). However `process.BeginOutputReadLine();`gives me the exception. The process I am trying to run is a simple batch file command `wmic product where "Name like '%%Microsoft Visual C++ %%'" get Name, Version` Stangely enough the `process.Exited` events works just fine.

Here is the code

```
  void DoSomething(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { textBox.Text = outLine.Data; }));
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string batPath = @"..\..\WMIC batch\";

        var process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batPath;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "Redistributable_Packages_Check.bat";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);

        process.OutputDataReceived +=new DataReceivedEventHandler(DoSomething);

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();

        StreamWriter sortStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        //textBox.Text = "Initialised";



    }

    private void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { textBox.Text = "Process has exited"; }));
    }
```

Exception details {"The system cannot find the file specified"}

P.S Omitting the lines

```
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

Triggers the batch file. So I believe it can find the file.

Comment: What happen when you try to run the command in cmd?

Comment: Try to specify an absolute path to the batch file: Process.Start("c:\yourfolder\WMIC batch\Redistributable_Packages_Check.bat");

Comment: @C0d1ngJammer When running command in cmd, it will display Microsoft packages installed on the system. So the top 4 results out of 30 for my system is:
 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4974         9.0.30729.4974   ,   
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86-x64 Compilers                            12.0.21005  , 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Debug Runtime - 14.0.24215               14.0.24215  ,  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219            10.0.40219  ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little example like yours and found that the reason is indeed (as mm8 mentioned in the comments) that you need to specify the *full path* for `process.StartInfo.FileName`. It's not enough to set the `WorkingDirectory`.

So for example:

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batPath;
process.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(batPath, "Redistributable_Packages_Check.bat");
```

---

The `WorkingDirectory` only specifies the path that relative file names used by the *new process* relate to. But the `FileName` is still relative to your current process' working directory.

Comment: OMG thank you! Full path for FileName. I spent a day on this issue.